# Creating new array of object from api call in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, google-calendar-api

I'm actually getting data from google calendar API for public holidays and I want to show them in the calendar. For that, I'm first getting the data from google API, and then I'm trying to create a new array of objects that will store the data that I needed from the google API calendar. The issue is I'm able to create a new array of objects but not able to add new objects for whole the data getting from the google calendar API. I try using loop but not work.

**My code**

```
let google;

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=personalkey')
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data.items;
            console.log("Google api calendar data", data)

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            data.map((item) => {
                google = {
                    "id": item.id,
                    "title": item.summary,
                    "location": "Australia",
                    "start": new Date(moment(item.start.date)),
                    "end": new Date(moment(item.end.date)),
                    "description": item.description,
                    "durationday": 'Fulllday',
                    "sameId": null

                }
            })
        }

        console.log("goggle making array of object inside promise", google)
    })
    .catch(err => { console.log('Google api calendar error', err) })
```

})

Comment: You currently have a `map`, whose function doesn't return anything, inside a `for` loop over the same data. `map` already iterates over the data, but unless something is returned from `map`'s function, you'll end up with an array of `undefined`. You also need to *capture* that map in order to use its results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a doubt,can i just use string literal and change google = {.....data} to google +=` {${.....data}` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are looping through the items twice. `for` loop and `map` both loop through the array. `map` is what you want and is used if want to modify an array but it requires that you return each object that you want to place in the new array. You should read about how to use map here [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So I think what you are trying to do is the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=personalkey')
    .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.items.map((item) => {
          return {
            "id": item.id,
            "title": item.summary,
            "location": "Australia",
            "start": new Date(moment(item.start.date)),
            "end": new Date(moment(item.end.date)),
            "description": item.description,
            "durationday": 'Fulllday',
            "sameId": null
          }
      })
    console.log("Your new array of modified objects here", data)
  })
  .catch(err => { console.log('Google api calendar error', err) })
}, [])
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do, Thank you for the answer.